# How to refer to the target value of list/dictionary comprehension in condition clause?

Tags: python

In the following examples,

```
[f(a) for a in range(10) if f(a) < 50]
{k: f(a) for k in range(10) if f(a) < 50}
```

Is it possible to eliminate the repeated `f(a)`, without introducing a wrapping list/dictionary comprehension?

Comment: In the second one the value is constant — is that intended?

Comment: @Cat it's just an example, it can be an arbitrary condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the repeated call to `f(a)` by introducing a dummy iteration over a single-element list:

```
(b for a in range(10) for b in [f(a)] if b < 50)
```

or by introducing a sub-generator:

```
(b for b in (f(a) for a in range(10)) if b < 50)
```

They are a bit inelegant, but they work, and are reasonably clear.

You'll probably be interested in [this long thread on the python-ideas mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-April/009797.html), in which Mathias Panzenböck proposes the addition of new syntax to the language to handle this case more elegantly. Generally, the response from the Python developers was that the problem isn't severe enough to warrant the additional complexity.

Comment: Nice. I'd go with the sub-generator for clarity. Also both versions perform insanely better in Python3 with the improved generators.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do this without wrapping list:

```
[for i in [f(a) for a in range(10)] if i<50]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd split this into 2 parts. You are applying `f` to the numbers in your range and then filtering thereon. Better to be more explicit - it makes your code simpler and means you don't have to run f(a) twice.

```
filter(lambda f_a: f_a < 50, [f(a) for a in range(10)])
```

with suitable variable names!

Alternatively, write it out with a loop explicitly. You lose some terseness, but it is often clearer what the code is doing and you have full control over what gets run where.

[edit]
It's bit more efficient to write it with a generator because it doesn't have to create the list and then iterate over it in the filter. (note the `[` `]` has been replaced with `(` `)`)

```
filter(lambda f_a: f_a < 50, (f(a) for a in range(10)))
```

Comment: The whole point of list comprehensions and generator expressions is to not have to use `filter` with a `lambda`.